# if select option blank, then select option 3

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectbox

Thank you in advance for anyone who helps on this one.

We have a drop down with a blank option in the first .

```
<select id="Flags">
<option></option>
<option value="Corporate">Corporate.png</option>
<option value="Store2">Store2.png</option>
</select>
```

If the first blank option is selected, how can I remove it and select "Store2"?

```
If $('#Flags option[value=""]')
Then .remove();
and $('#Flags').val ("Store2")
```

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("#Flags").change(function() {
    if (!$(this).val()) 
        $(this).val("Store2");
});
```

It would be better to just have `Store2` as the default with not blank option, as you may confuse your users if they choose the blank item, yet see 'Store2.png' selected.

Comment: If you're using jQuery 1.7+, the event shortcuts (`click()`, `change()`, `keypress()`, etc.) all use `on()` behind the scenes anyway.